# How to render System Message from AJAX call

Tags: joomla-3.x, ajax, javascript

I would like to display a system message when I got back my ajax request.

The ajax request returns the right message. I can test it with an alert.

```
alert(result.message);
Joomla.renderMessages(result.message);
```

It will now show up the success or error message as a typical Joomla System Message.
But the `Joomla.renderMessages` call, doesn't show any results. The system message won't appear on my site.

Is there anything wrong or do I have to do something more to get this to run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the things mentioned by @Bakual are correct but I notice that you are just passing the `result.message` to `alert` and given that `[alert(message)][1]` expects `message` to be a `string` or an `object` it can convert to a `string` this could be the problem.

If `result.message` is just a string, then you will need to wrap it in an appropriate container, something like this:

```
var jmsgs = [result.message];  // You can stack multiple messages of the same type
Joomla.renderMessages({'info': jmsgs });
```

Comment: that's the solution! Thx!

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript function depends on the presence of a container with the id `system-message-container`. Some templates don't have this container at all, or only if there is a message to show. So first check with Protostar and see if it works there

Also you need to make sure you actually loaded `core.js` with your extension. It isn't necessary loaded, especially not in frontend.
Since Joomla 3.3 you can load it using `JHtmlBehavior::core()`, in earlier version you would use `JHtmlBehavior::framework()`.